# NodeJS s3 zip/csv download, can't read file

Tags: node.js, csv, amazon-s3, papaparse, node-csv-parse

i'm using AWS's developer [Reporting API](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/reports-promo/reporting-API.html#use-the-s3-url-to-download-the-report) in order to download a zip file containing a CSV sales report.

My problem is, I cannot read this file and i can't for the life of me figure out why. Whilst on the server terminal, `cat my.csv` prints the file perfectly, as plain-english CSV, yet the command `file my.csv` prints `ASCII text, with very long lines`.

When I downloaded the file with SCP to my local machine and opened it, it opened perfectly with macOS Numbers. My machine also downloaded the file as `CSV Text` type, according to `file my.csv` output, despite the fact on the server it was `ASCII`.

On my server, I cannot read this csv file using NodeJS packages for parsing CSV files and unzipping.

**1. First my scripts start with downloading the zip file:**

```
export async function downloadS3Zip(url, destination) {
    const response = await axios.get(url, { responseType: "stream"});
    const writer = fs.createWriteStream(destination, { "encoding": "utf-8"});// i've also tried without this option
    response.data.pipe(writer);
    const [failed, finished] = await to(checkFileWrite(writer));
    if (failed) throw new Error('failed to write zip file to ', destination);
    if (finished) log(`finished writing zip file to ${destination}`);
    if (!finished) throw new Error("download s3 func: check file write didn't resolve properly.")
}
export async function checkFileWrite(writeStream) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        writeStream.on("finish", () => {
            resolve(true)
        })
        writeStream.on("error", () => {
            reject(true)
        });
    });
}
```

**2. Then I unzip this file using `node-stream-zip`**

```
export async function unzipZipFile(destination) {
    const zip = new NodeStreamZip.async({ file: destination });
    let finalFile;
    zip.on('error', (err) => {
        throw new Error(err)
    });
    zip.on('ready', () => log('All entries read: ', zip.entriesCount))
    zip.on('extract', (entry, file) => {
        log(`Extracted ${entry.name} to ${file}`);
        log(entry)
        finalFile = file;
    });
    await zip.extract(null, ZIP_DOWNLOAD_LOCATION);
    await zip.close();
    if (!finalFile) throw new Error('no file returned from unzip func.')
    return finalFile
}
```

**3. At this point, my directory will have the .zip file and .csv file**

**4. I've tried using `papaparse` and `csv-parse`, to no avail:**

```
// papaparse example
export async function readCSVFile(filePath) {
    const csvFile = fs.readFileSync(filePath)
    const csvData = csvFile.toString()
    console.log("\n\nBeginning parse..........")
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        Papa.parse(csvData, {
            header: true,
            complete: results => {
                log('\nComplete', results.data.length, 'records.')
                resolve(results.data)
            }
        })
    })
}
```

When outputting the `results.data` array, i get stuff like this

```
{
  'PK\x03\x04\x14\x00\b\b\b\x00[E�T\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x17\x00\x00\x00sales-2022-06-00000.csv̽Y��ز6': "Ǿ:'B�w̓#�Bb\x14�Y���\x00I�@�b���Z��ݮR�sl*\f{w��媲2�V�ӓ��~\x19\x1D��8����>���\x1D����Kn\x13F��>m� ���\ro?^������\x7Fz�*��\x13�mdX��\x1EV����\x06Q���}�o�۰�xm��u��\x7F�T��\x17\x1F\x12��\x1C�՗�x��G��w֦��~�\x1C'i����~p�_e�A�0>\x1CS���\x0F��t<��O�e����:����\x12/���1��_i\x14l�a��F�o����}�\x0E�Fg���m�����\x15�m\x14�C�\x1A\x1F��Ka�_��Y�o_��g�a�",
  '��': 'i��C',
  __parsed_extra: [
    'qBC?z7�\x1F�v\x14DJ\x00���g�Ʒ���`�2�\x1D\x03F"�\x06r\x02\b\x16t:a\x04N!\x00p\x02ǂ�\x01"�\x18O�0$\x06"�R�$��c\x03\x01�L�M��\x00��ЯP~i�=��L��F}c�@���\\�T����>>D��8^��\x7FhstPj���N�U؉W�d',
    'P�,�\x17��Ϸ�}�?_�\x7F�\x7F��я�er5��\x12\x12\x1AJ������0�\x1FX\x1Ay\x00MA\x00\x05��P\x00� 4�*�ɭ�-�I�x\x1D�(��I@��\x13˸��G�\\���ٛ\x01��\b�\x00�ðV\x06��VWn��.�0-\x0EK\x13�W�\x0E���Vo�}�_!�e�"� Q\x1A�\x00ȿ�\x0B� ����\x10��z!A�bfr( ���]G��u\x1A����\x10s^\x18��5W���5�O��',
    `Q/�ڠ��:oƞ\\���r��K\x00/��V'Or-�&E�Jv�0����9+y��A�\x12�\x11�@i\x18�\x1F�\x0B�\x12�WU���q\x06LI\t\x15�\x1Bt],�n�Z�� \\���\x14�\x0F\x0505�=��-���!�*;�ݼ\x19�c\x7Fȏf��\x18y�,��(��a�P����\x14���m�LN���Q�"�\x19U�\x0B�g`,
    '�^�\x15��z��D�\x15\x02\x13�^Z�\x12�_�',
    '�^D^X�L�G�����\ta�f\x071)��:���0l\x13�?,%�{׳���v�\x16�d�OrpVơ�\x0EP�ޏ��V��\x11�\x16̮W�]\x0B9��\f��d\x19�J1:?�^\x01(�\x122�!���/��4',
    '%ߌon>�Ϣ�8X���\x01�@Rf"A���8WD����\x1A+\x0E\x161�{r޾���\t�´?;1g5�V�U���\x1B���]�Ly岪\x0F��+/\x15Z\r~>��vi�^�\x07�i�Ņ�Q�&\x00�D= �\x19:F��c��\x04�'
  ]
} {
  'PK\x03\x04\x14\x00\b\b\b\x00[E�T\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x17\x00\x00\x00sales-2022-06-00000.csv̽Y��ز6': '�0\x04�I1�\r��.\x11�NЩ��QnV"�5\x18��m��-ߙ�ڭ��l�\x19��jI�Q��C䭶}yq�q\x05vv�\t��h׿m�QW�,�0��\x1Ea��g\x19%�ݬ\x12t��So��fJ��똍�l�~��O6!�\x7F7\x1C���ƒ�uc����Dy�����U���X\x1D���+M� ��8�K#q���mE.<"K]�m\x7F��°\bɰ}\r�Yno.A�/��[�6ą�\x15�k�*�<}�\x1C\x12A�xg]c����3Q�a��w}O���Z,��k\x06�Ӣ>��\x01eq�\x04���\x1E������\fp�_���T(&�B����]��K�\x1C�p��3\x04���}\x7F��\x15���\x1E�#M\x10i\x02(��x�u+u��l\x15f�-g�k����\x19u�ۢ>��\x05���\x07%uFc��6]R���o�'
} {
```

```
// csv-parse example...
export async function parseCSVFile(filePath) {    
    const records = [];
    const parser = fs.createReadStream(filePath).pipe(parse({ relax_quotes: true}));

    parser.on("readable", () => {
        let record;
        while ((record = parser.read()) !== null) {
            records.push(record);
        }
    });
    await finished(parser);
    return records;
}
```

The above example throws an error:

```
CsvError: Invalid Record Length: expect 1, got 5 on line 4
    at Object.__onRecord (file:///usr/src/app/node_modules/csv-parse/lib/api/index.js:353:11)
    at Object.parse (file:///usr/src/app/node_modules/csv-parse/lib/api/index.js:238:40)
    at Parser._transform (file:///usr/src/app/node_modules/csv-parse/lib/index.js:31:26)
    at Parser.Transform._write (node:internal/streams/transform:184:23)
    at writeOrBuffer (node:internal/streams/writable:389:12)
    at _write (node:internal/streams/writable:330:10)
    at Parser.Writable.write (node:internal/streams/writable:334:10)
    at ReadStream.ondata (node:internal/streams/readable:749:22)
    at ReadStream.emit (node:events:394:28)
    at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:312:12) {
  code: 'CSV_RECORD_INCONSISTENT_FIELDS_LENGTH',
  bytes: 1080,
  comment_lines: 0,
  empty_lines: 0,
  invalid_field_length: 0,
  lines: 4,
  records: 1,
  columns: false,
  error: undefined,
  header: false,
  index: 5,
  raw: undefined,
  column: 5,
  quoting: false,
  record: [
    'Ǿ:\'B�w̓#�Bb\x14�Y���\x00I�@�b���Z��ݮR�sl*\f{w��媲2�V�ӓ��~\x19\x1D��8����>���\x1D����Kn\x13F��>m� ���\ro?^������\x7Fz�*��\x13�mdX��\x1EV����\x06Q���}�o�۰�xm��u��\x7F�T��\x17\x1F\x12��\x1C�՗�x��G��w֦��~�\x1C\'i����~p�_e�A�0>\x1CS���\x0F��t<��O�e����:����\x12/���1��_i\x14l�a��F�o����}�\x0E�Fg���m�����\x15�m\x14�C�\x1A\x1F��Ka�_��Y�o_��g�a�|i��C|qBC?z7�\x1F�v\x14DJ\x00���g�Ʒ���`�2�\x1D\x03F"�\x06r\x02\b\x16t:a\x04N!\x00p\x02ǂ�\x01"�\x18O�0$\x06"�R�$��c\x03\x01�L�M��\x00��ЯP~i�=��L��F}c�@���\\�T����>>D��8^��\x7FhstPj���N�U؉W�d|P�',
    `�\x17��Ϸ�}�?_�\x7F�\x7F��я�er5��\x12\x12\x1AJ������0�\x1FX\x1Ay\x00MA\x00\x05��P\x00� 4�*�ɭ�-�I�x\x1D�(��I@��\x13˸��G�\\���ٛ\x01��\b�\x00�ðV\x06��VWn��.�0-\x0EK\x13�W�\x0E���Vo�}�_!�e�"� Q\x1A�\x00ȿ�\x0B� ����\x10��z!A�bfr( ���]G��u\x1A����\x10s^\x18��5W���5�O��|Q/�ڠ��:oƞ\\���r��K\x00/��V'Or-�&E�Jv�0����9+y��A�\x12�\x11�@i\x18�\x1F�\x0B�\x12�WU���q\x06LI\t\x15�\x1Bt]`,
    '�n�Z�� \\���\x14�\x0F\x0505�=��-���!�*;�ݼ\x19�c\x7Fȏf��\x18y�',
    '��(��a�P����\x14���m�LN���Q�"�\x19U�\x0B�g|�^�\x15��z��D�\x15\x02\x13�^Z�\x12�_�|�^D^X�L�G�����\ta�f\x071)��:���0l\x13�?',
    '%�{׳���v�\x16�d�OrpVơ�\x0EP�ޏ��V��\x11�\x16̮W�]\x0B9��\f��d\x19�J1:?�^\x01(�\x122�!���/��4|%ߌon>�Ϣ�8X���\x01�@Rf"A���8WD����\x1A+\x0E\x161�{r޾���\t�´?;1g5�V�U���\x1B���]�Ly岪\x0F��+/\x15Z\r~>��vi�^�\x07�i�Ņ�Q�&\x00�D= �\x19:F��c��\x04�'
  ]
}
```

How can i parse this file in NodeJS that is apparently in ASCII format?

Comment: How are you calling these different methods?  What is being passed to `readCSVFile` ?

Comment: in a single script, i'm calling them in the numeric order given in my answer. ```readCSVFile``` receives a file path as a string, which is the path to the CSV file.

Comment: That seems unlikely.  The `results.data` you showed contains a zip file, not a csv file.